# Capistrano 3 deploys a wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, capistrano3

On my production machine

```
rbenv versions
system
* 2.2.2 (set by /Users/smi/.rbenv/version)

which unicorn
/Users/smi/.rbenv/shims/unicorn

ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

On my server (I can not understand why unicorn gets **ruby version 2.2.0** after a deploy and where from, because is not installed on any of my machines):

```
rbenv versions
* 2.2.2 (set by /home/deployuser/.rbenv/version)

bundle exec which unicorn
/var/www/foreignernetwork/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn
```

.rbenv/version

```
2.2.2
```

Comment: hmmm i did not declare a version, just wrote   **gem 'capistrano3-nginx_unicorn'**
in Gemfile.lock is     **capistrano3-nginx_unicorn (0.0.6)**
If I run **bundle exec rbenv versions** in my deployed app on Server (folder current) it has a result: **bundle exec rbenv versions
  system
* 2.2.2 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)**

Answer (score 2):

It is not getting a different version of Ruby.  You're running 2.2.2, but Bundler just uses a 2.2.0 directory for storing the bundled gems, bins, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it seems everything is ok, I only beed to add a secret key